# how to sync/flush after fdisk in linux (busybox)

Tags: linux, fdisk, busybox

when I change the partition table in Linux (busybox) and exit fdisk I'm still able to mount the old partitions,  until I perform a reboot

for example

```
a)  system is setup and has a /dev/sda1  and /dev/sda2 
b)  enter fdisk, delete both partition 1 and 2 
c)  save and exit 
d)  attempt to mount /dev/sda1, this succeeds when I think it should fail
```

I would assume d) would fail since the partition has been deleted?  what am I missing?

Comment: how about running "sync"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS must be "forced" to re-read the partition table once changes have been done. A reboot does this and hence you see fdisk changes after a reboot.

I've used the following command before to re-read partition table and I didn't have to reboot,

```
# partprobe
```

- partprobe is part of parted package